# multithread pause and resume

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i want to learn  working logic about thread pause and resume.

```
Thread th=new Thread(start);
th.Start();

public void start()
{
    command_1;
    command_2;
    command_3;

    if(variable_condition)
        goto Pause;

    command_4;
    command_5;
    command_6;
    command_7;

    Pause:
        pause();
}

private void pause()
{
    th.Suspend();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    th.Resume();
}
```

Now, When the command which starts the thread continue?

command_1 or command_4 ?

Comment: So, do a [little reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x(v=vs.110).aspx): "Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume... However, the use of these methods is not recommended... The Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume methods are not generally useful for applications and should not be confused with synchronization mechanisms." - so, why are you learning them, specifically?

Comment: Because i am not good about multithreading. And i know just this methods for pause and resume. if such methods, can you give me link about these methods. 
I would be grateful

Comment: Unlearn the use of `Suspend` and `Resume` and read about synchronization objects, such as mutexes, critical sections, locks, semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

As per code written your `Resume` will not do a thing since start function execution is already at label `Pause`. So, you are resuming at the end, and the function simply ends upon resume.

If you want to resume from command_4, then change

```
if(variable_condition)
    goto Pause;
```

to

```
if(variable_condition)
    pause();
```

and remove label `Pause`

Alternatively, if gods of coding demand GOTO to be used:

```
Thread th=new Thread(start);
th.Start();

public void start()
{
    command_1;
    command_2;
    command_3;

    if(variable_condition)
        goto Pause;

    Pause:
        pause();

    command_4;
    command_5;
    command_6;
    command_7;
}

private void pause()
{
    th.Suspend();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    th.Resume();
}
```

It is very stupid, but ...

Comment: firstly thank you for your answer. but i need use "goto" command this line.

Comment: enjoy GOTO. added answer with GOTO.

Comment: pls look following my answer mate